# jquery function constant monitoring

Tags: html, jquery

Let's say I got the folloning testing html code:

```
<button class="button is-small is-danger is-light" id="choose">choose</button>
```

and the following jquery code:

```
  function c3 () { $("#choose").click(function() { alert("clicked")})}
```

once a click is registered an alert goes of withe the message "clicked".
this happens when the c3 function is executed.
But suppose I want the c3 function to constantly wait for an click event? How do I get the function to constantly monitor the id tag?

Comment: `$("#choose").click(function() { alert("clicked")})`

Comment: no, it registers one click, and then it needs to be executed again...

Comment: Its not clear what you mean. an event listener does constantly wait in ready for whatever event it is listening to. in effect, the monitoring you describe. What exactly  are you trying to accomplish

Comment: If I declare the function in either the html file or in the developer console in opera it only register one click and after that I have to execute the function again. What I want is that the function should monitor the button al the time. there is no need for a function that just register one click and then exit.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I now understand how this works. Every time I click on the button the whole page is reloaded and subsequently the jquery function is gone. All my functions reside in a scripts.js file on the server side. The solution is to have the jquery function on the page that is being reloaded.
I hope this is heplfull for others.